# Rails 6.1 failed migrations no longer block rails from running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In the past when there were migrations which didn't run yet, there would be an error '*pending migrations*' that would prohibit rails (server, console) from starting.

I've updated to Rails 6.1 and have a failing migration.  Nevertheless the server is running and I can go into the console without any warning.

The migration that is failing is a ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1] migration.

Is this intended? Is there a way of going back to the old behavior?  We use Kubernetes and a failed migration just blocks the new pod from coming live which is perfect.

Comment: Are you using release candidate 2? I tried it, and it still behaves as it did in previous versions of rails when running `bin/rails server`.

Comment: @RyanSandridge yes, RC2.  I do have multi database setup, maybe that's related.  The migration was in the primary DB though.